# How to improve opencv image filter?

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, imagefilter

there was a problem with creating filters to the photo. For example, I need to make the effect of a scanned document.
simple code

```
  val mat = Mat(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, CvType.CV_8UC1)
  Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)

  Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
  Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255.0, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 15.0)

  val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
  Utils.matToBitmap(mat, result)
  mat.release()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVNI7.jpg)

also i tried another method but the result is worse

```
  val mat = Mat(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, CvType.CV_8UC1)
  Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)

  Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  Imgproc.medianBlur(mat, mat, 5)
  Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255.0, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 3.0)

  val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
  Utils.matToBitmap(mat, result)
  mat.release()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goMV1.jpg)

i also tried other combinations and pass different values, but it doesn't work out better, i want to achieve something like below, at least improve the first method. I looked at many different algorithms, but I don't know how to implement them in the code, I'll be glad if you help me with examples, thanks!

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMO6n.jpg)

original image

[origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtAER.jpg)

Comment: source picture is close to unworkable. dark/noisy. don't expect too much. some of your results are already good.